# How can I use sqlite3 Python to insert values from a JSON but at the same time check if the value already exists?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

My goal is to insert values from a JSON, this already works. But how can I check if the values I insert from my JSON are already in my table?

Unfortunately, the current code does not work. The error is:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error`

My Code:

```py
def add_authors_to_table(self, authors):

        self.cursor.executemany('''
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO author (AuthorID, FirstName, LastName) 
        VALUES (:Author_ID, :FirstName, :LastName)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT AuthorID FROM author WHERE AuthorID = 
        authors[Author_ID])''', authors)

        self.db.saveChanges()

        return 200
```

Comment: If `AuthorID` is defined as primary key or unique then just remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: What do you mean by leaving out the Where clause?

Comment: `executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO author (AuthorID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (:Author_ID, :FirstName, :LastName)", authors)`